# iFrame doesn't load from codepen or any other sites

Tags: javascript, iframe, widget, embed

I have created html page:
   http://time.graphics/embed?v=1&id=4

I want create widget embed code:

```
<iframe width="600" height="400" 
        src="" http://time.graphics/embed?v=1&id=4
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But it doesn't work, here the codepen:
https://codepen.io/jenkaman/pen/MoQzNo

Please, help. What's going on? How to create widget, which will be shown on any website. Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is that codepen is disable iframes from foreign authors.

Comment: no. any other wesites blocks too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! 
Need use a **https**!